# ExtJS Turn combobox to displayfield

Tags: extjs, combobox, grid, displayfield

I have a grid with RowEditing that has a combobox.
When certain conditions are met, I want to turn that combo to a displayfield (I want the combo to just display its value, no button and not editable).
For now, when the conditions are met, I just disable the combobox; but it looks kinda funky that way. That's why I want to change.

Answer (score 0):

Easy as cake, thanks to [`disabledCls` configuration](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-disabledCls).

```
editor:{
    xtype:'combobox',
    disabledCls:'some-css-class'
}
```

Then you can "turn the combobox to displayfield" using `disable()`, and it won't grey out.

To hide the button, you have to add some basic CSS:

```
.some-css-class .x-form-trigger {
    display:none;
}
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1b8d

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It appears a box either way and the box doesn't resize in order to fill the missing button so I believe it is better as a default disabled. I was thinking that the combo should look more like a displayfield (no box and no button)

Comment: Then you are using a different theme and would possibly have to change the CSS a bit.

Comment: Changing the CSS can make the box disappear? I would like that. Only text, no box and no button

Comment: Delete the CSS file or remove it from index.html and check what's left. That's the part you can't change by changing the CSS. (if you don't want to test: If you remove the CSS, the page will either be completely blank or some black text fragments on white background...)